# Bugzilla xmlrpc not returning \ (backslash)

Tags: bugzilla

I am accessing `bugzilla` ( *version 4.4.9* ) over `xmlrpc`. I can get the data correctly except for one problem. The backslashes `"\"` in the comments were removed by the server. I have examined the `HTTP` packet with `wireshark` to check if the server is really sending it or not. In the `wireshark` packet the backslashes `"\"` are missing. ( The backslashes are part of a windows path )

Is there an option I need to set in the request for the server to send the contents with the backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing another server to make sure your request is correct?

Comment: I am getting the reply correctly except for this absent backslashes. I will search for a public bugzilla server to test. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the confusion. Looks like it is a data problem in my server. It is NOT an issue with xmlrpc.

Can someone please close this question.

Thanks for the replies and help.